# Random Characters being stored in a file

Tags: c++, class, object, file-handling

I have created an `Admins` class with three data members `(adminID, adminName, adminPhone)` and an array of objects for that same class. The data of each object is to be stored in a `.txt` file.

There is no run-time error and the program works as expected but upon opening the file in notepad, I found that there are random characters in the file.

Here's the class declaration:

```
class Admins
{
    private:
        int adminID;
        char adminName[100];
        char adminPhone[11];

    public:
        Admins()
        {
            adminID = 0;
            strcpy(adminName, "NULL");
            strcpy(adminPhone, "NULL");
        }
        void addAdminData();
        void writeAdminData();
        void readAdminData();
};
```

This is the snippet for writing the data:

```
void Admins::writeAdminData()
{
    if(adminID == 0)
        cout<<"Admin Data not initialized";
    else
    {
        ofstream fout;
        fout.open("AdminData.txt", ios::app);
        fout.write((char*)this, sizeof(*this));
        fout.close();
    }
}
```

This is what the file looked like:

```
   Aryan Soni   šÐo    ÿÿÿÿ     šÐo    ÿÿÿÿ                  @@     €               ¶@     ØNr     583963728
```

Comment: `fout.write()` writes raw bytes to the file. These raw ("binary") data cannot be viewed as text. If you want to write text representations of each member, you must do so explicitly with `fout << adminName`, for example. (And you must write according code if you want to read it in again.)

Comment: If you do want to save raw object data, you need to use `ios::binary` for portability.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Oh yes. Can I do something like `ios::app|ios::binary`?

Comment: Yes sure, that's how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Concept

Those are not random character, instead they are the raw bytes of your class stored on stack-memory for a single instance and will be completely random in another instance of your application. In short, those "random" characters are garbage bytes beyond null terminating (`'\0'`) character in your string.

##### FIX

```cpp
fout.write((char*)this, sizeof(*this));
```

Change the above line to the below line:

```cpp
fout << this->adminID << this->adminName << this->adminPhone;
```

You can format the data in order to read it again and parse it.

Comment: This seemed to have fixed the problem. Now it just needs a bit of formatting to look nice. BTW, the first digit of the phone number is omitted. I think that is because of the null terminating character of the entered string. Am I correct?

Comment: In the test case, the `adminID` (int) was 1. But it was showing as a random character that this website doesn't support (I pasted the exact file but it seems to have disappeared)

Comment: @AryanSoni Consider asking a new question, solving it in a comment section would be hard

Comment: The simplest way to format would probably be `fout << this->adminID << " " << std::quoted(this->adminName) << " " << std::quoted(this->adminPhone) << "\n";` (and also use `std::quoted` when reading). If you do switch to formatted data, consider using `std::string` instead of raw character arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I think I fixed the problem. The problem was that because of the `'\0'` first character of the next string was ignored

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. This looks a lot nicer. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

You declared `adminID` as int so it will be written in binary form, likely 0x00000001, assuming admin's ID is 1. Rest are strings, so `adminName`, `adminPhone` should be visible as strings (formally), in "natural language" in notepad.

That's how it is going to look in the file (int is assumed to be 32-bit):

```
00000000  01 00 00 00 61 64 6d 69  6e 35 35 35 31 32 33 34  |....admin5551234|
00000010  35                                                |5|
00000011
```

There are more problems with it. Strings are not terminated in the file so trying to read it one only can know size of int (4 bytes) and the rest is going to be string of characters, unable to differentiate between names. These names should either be terminated somehow (with 0x00, or new line or whatever), or fixed length written to file.

Comment: They are. 0x... denotes hexadecimal, I did't say it will look like string "0x00000001" - that's not the same thing.

Comment: You don't get it. So, how are you going to print here binary 1, or 0x00000001 for tht matter?

Comment: You're right. The `txt` file displayed `adminName`  and `adminPhone` as strings like you said, in "natural language"

Comment: As said in the answer, your strings are not terminated in any way so when you will eventually try to read them you won't know their boundaries.